# PI 3B wifi interface fail

Tags: pi-3, wifi, ubuntu

My PI-3B is flashed with Ubuntu 16.04 with *wireless-tools* and *wpa_supplicant* also installed.

My issue is I can't get **wlan0** to be recognised by the system either dynamically (DHCP) or statically.

I am using the following config data in **/etc/network/interfaces**:

```
source-directory /etc/network/interfaces.d
source /etc/network/interfaces.d/*.cfg

auto wlan0
#iface wlan0 inet dhcp
iface wlan0 inet static

address 192.168.0.40
netmask 255.255.255.0
network 192.168.0.0
broadcast 192.168.0.255
gateway 192.168.0.1
dns-nameservers 192.168.0.1, 8.8.8.8

wpa-wssid WIFI-NETWORK-NAME
wpa-psk WIFI-NETWORK-PASSWORD
```

**TO ELIMINATE HARD ISSUES,** On the same Pi, but with a different SD card flashed with Raspbian, wifi connection works with the following settings in */etc/network/interfaces*:

```
allow-hotplug wlan0
iface wlan0 inet manual
   wpa-conf /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf
```

So, the issue does not seem to be hardware related.

Can anyone help, please?

Answer (score 0):

It is not entirely clear what you are using - "Ubuntu 16.04" is ambiguous, I am assuming the version of Ubuntu MATE linked from the Foundation site.

1. Ubuntu uses [predictable network interface names](https://www.debian.org/releases/stretch/amd64/release-notes/ch-whats-new.en.html#new-interface-names) so **WILL NOT** have `wlan0` (this may not apply to Pi3 as onboard WiFi chip is connected by sdio)
2. Ubuntu uses `NetworkManager` which **DOES NOT** use `/etc/network/interfaces`

If you want to use Ubuntu configure it through the GUI - the way it is designed to work.

You DO NOT need to install any tools to make it work, and attempting to do so may  interfere with other pre-installed software.

PS The settings you listed for Raspbian are OBSOLETE. See [How to set up networking/WiFi](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/37921/8697)